# Multivariate system of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, computer-algebra-systems

I have a large (~1000 equations) overdetermined system of degree 3 polynomials with ~140 variables.

I would like to find a complete solution set for this system, however, the Gröbner basis seems to be too large to compute.

The first 100 equations can easily be factored/solved resulting in ~100 solutions.

Plugging one of these solutions into the remaining equations results in a new set of equations which also has a subset that can easily be solved.

Is there a way to obtain all solutions other than a brute force method of examining every possible case (the number of cases to consider grows quite fast)?

Comment: Resultant and factoring give more profit for analysis of system, than the Gröbner basis

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: It's hard for me to explain, can help other examples from search "resultant" on MSE

Comment: Have you tried software for numerical solutioen -- e.g. the system Bertini?